# Should I install SQL Server on a SSD drive (educational purposes only)?

Tags: ssd, sql-server

I have just started using a 120 GB SSD drive on my laptop. I wonder if it is a good idea to install SQL-Server on this partition. I am sure I will want to install Management Studio there but what about the database server?

I am going to use this instance only to practice SQL. I will definetely execute poorly optimized queries but probably the databases will be small.

Should I worry about using up the read/write cycles on the device? As far as I know one they are limited.

Comment: I would store the DB on the SSD and not the server.

Answer (score 1):

I’d say yes. Mainly because you’ll fire much for `SELECT` statements at the database, and reading doesn’t affect the lifetime of an SSD. And you’d have to `INSERT` a lot of data to really feel any negative side effects. In a production environment it can be different, depending on what the database is used for. But if you’re just learning it should be no problem.

This article—[*The SSD Endurance Experiment*](http://techreport.com/review/25889/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-500tb-update)—might be of interest too:

> The rationale for our endurance test hasn't changed, which is why
>   these intros tend to channel the same theme. Solid-state drives use
>   flash memory that has limited write endurance. Every time data is
>   written, the physical structure of the NAND cells degrades. The cells
>   eventually erode to the point where they become unusable, forcing SSDs
>   to poach replacement blocks from their overprovisioned spare areas.